# Data Structure to store Token Properties

Tags: parsing, rust, interpreter, lexical-analysis

I am writing an interpreter for a mathematical language in Rust which is intended to be used to solve mathematical expressions.

When **lexing**, the program needs to know based on the characters used in a token, what type of token it is (for example is it a function or an operator).

Currently I use an enumeration to represent a type of token:

```
pub enum IdentifierType {
    Function,
    Variable,
    Operator,
    Integer,
}
```

To check the type of a token I use a function which takes an `IdentifierType` as input and matches based on input to return a `bool`. The data structures that could be used in this case are relatively simple as tokens only have a single property: allowed characters.

When **parsing** to an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST), I would like to know what specific operator or function is being used based on a token and to be able to add a reference to that operator and its associated functions to the AST.

When **interpreting**, I would like to be able to call execute on a node and have it know how to perform its own function.

I have tried to come up with a solution to store all of these related items, but none that I have encountered as felt satisfactory.

For example I stored all of the operators in a TOML file (a type of configuration file that maps to a hash table) but storing enumerations (values that are constrained) is difficult and there is no way to store an operators function. I also want to be able to search by multiple keys, such as operator associativity (e.g. get all operators that are right associative), which means storing within source code is not very satisfactory.

Other possible ideas I have had are using some kind of SQL hybrid system, however that seems tough to implement

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While interesting, this question has a very **broad** set of answers that might hinge on the **opinion** of the answerer. You should read through [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a sense of what is and is not a good fit for this site. For this specific question, I'd suggest showing us **example code** that you have with concrete questions about why it doesn't do what you want.